# Micronutrient requirements

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition

[image: this is what usually i eat]Since everybody talks about the importance of macronutrients in a fat-loss and muscle-building program but nobody talks about the quantity in which these micronutrients are required for a gym goer.

I'm following a calorie deficit diet and working out and i have got a little darkness under my eyes..i think i'm missing something

I don't have a workout routine... I just do lat pull downs, squats (3 days per week), bicep curls, forearm curls, pec flys, tricep extensions, dumbbell rows, lateral raises. I do this daily. 3 sets of 10-15 reps and last till failure.

My age : 18.6
Weight : 71kg
Height : 165cm
B.F. % : 28% (approx)

I'm learning chest and shoulder press from 'Starting Strength' by Mark Rippetoe.

Comment: Do you mean macronutrients (i.e. protein, carbs and fat), or micronutrients (i.e. vitamins and minerals)?

Comment: Vitamins and minerals

Answer (score 1):

Micronutrient recommendations are published by the US Food and Drug Administration, and other national health bodies, as "Reference Daily Intake" (RDI) values. These are easily accessible, just search for "RDI" and the vitamin or mineral of interest. RDIs are generally determined for a 2000 kcal/day diet, so if you are eating substantially more than that, then just scale upwards in proportion to your actual daily calorie consumption.

And if you're concerned about a specific problem, like darkness under your eyes, see a doctor and ask them about it. Taking guesses as to micronutrients that you may be deficient in is unlikely to yield positive results.

Comment: While humans are humans, you are assuming that the RDI is the best published index, and the OP is most likely from an Indian based culture (Going by the name and some of the dietary elements). The RDI is a decent starting point, however.